# Assembly x8086 swap array values

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I have a question to write a code that will get 8 chars/numbers
and it will swap every 2 bytes between them.

Example :

input 451ABD45

ARR = |34|35|31|41|42|44|34|35

NewARR = |35|34|41|31|44|42|35|34

output 54A1DB54

My Code:

```
STA SEGMENT STACK
    DB 100H DUP (0)
STA ENDS

DATA SEGMENT
    MSG DB 'Please Enter 8 Chars : $'
    DIM DW 10 DUP(?)
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA,SS:STA
MAIN:
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    LEA DX, MSG
    MOV AH, 9H
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 10
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 13
    MOV CX, 8
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV DX, 0
INPUT:
    MOV AH, 1H
    INT 21H
    MOV AH, 0
    MOV DIM[BX], AX
    INC BX
    LOOP INPUT
    MOV CX, 4
    MOV BX, 0
EXCHANGE:
    MOV DX, DIM[BX] ;0
    INC BX ;1
    MOV AX, DIM[BX] ;1
    DEC BX ;0
    MOV DIM[BX], AX ;0
    ADD BX, 1 ;1
    MOV DIM[BX], DX ;1
    INC BX
    LOOP EXCHANGE
    MOV DL, 10
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 13
    MOV CX, 8
    MOV BX, 0
    MOV DX, 0
PRINT:
    MOV DX, DIM[BX]
    INC BX
    MOV AH, 2H
    INT 21H
    LOOP PRINT
    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
CODE ENDS
    END MAIN
```

My_input 451ABD45

ARR = |34|35|31|41|42|44|34|35

MY_NewARR = |35|34|41|35|44|41|35|44

My_output 54A5DA5D

What wrong with my code, thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

You're loading and storing words (16-bit values), while your characters are one bytes each.

For example, before the first iteration you have this:

```
'4','5','1','A','B','D','4','5'
```

And after the first iteration you're supposed to have this:

```
'5','4','1','A','B','D','4','5'
 |   |
 \  /
swapped
```

But what you end up doing is this:

```
'5','1','1','A','B','D','4','5'
|    |
\   /
AX is stored

'5','4','5','A','B','D','4','5'
    |    |
    \   /
    DX is stored
```

And so on for the rest of the string.

---

A fixed and somewhat simplified swap loop could look like this:

```
EXCHANGE:
  MOV DH,BYTE PTR [BX + DIM]   ; First character in high byte of DX
  MOV DL,BYTE PTR [BX + DIM+1] ; Second character in low byte of DX
  MOV [BX + DIM],DX            ; DX contains the byte-swapped pair
  ADD BX,2                     ; Move to next pair of characters
  LOOP EXCHANGE
```

Comment: It's didn't work. Its give me an error Operand types do not match   MOV DH,[BX + DIM]    
  MOV DL,[BX + DIM+1]

Comment: Ok, that's a TASM issue. Try using `BYTE PTR` (e.g. `MOV DH, BYTE PTR [BX + DIM]`)

Comment: Excellent,  Thanks a lot =D (what do BYTE PTR?)

Comment: It's a size specifier telling TASM that even though `DIM` is declared as an array of words, you want to access a single byte.